# Is there a noun for "unpaid debts"?

Tags: single-word-requests

In Italian there is a noun, "insoluto" (noun), which is used when a creditor notices that the debtor will not pay the debt. Generally the creditor will decide to entrust to a lawyer this "unpaid debt".
I've found "unpaid debt" and "outstanding debt", but no one of them is a noun.
Is there a specific noun for this concept in english? If no, which term or compound word (if there is no term) is the most correct? 
An example:

> I always entrust to a lawyer in case of _____

Comment: Surely all debts are unpaid.

Comment: Do you mean a debt that somebody has failed to pay by the due date? Such debts are "in default".

Comment: In this case I'm talking about debts that the debitor is not going to pay since the "expiration date" is passed. Business generally do not pay when they place the order and this operation generates a debt (that usually the debitor pays in the next days/months). In this case the creditor notice the debitor won't pay so the creditor entrust to a lawyer this "unpaid debt".

Comment: Then yes, such debts are "in default", and in your example sentence you'd say "...in case of default". By the way, it's "debtor", not "debitor".

Comment: Perhaps a collection agency—a business that tries to collect? Or a lawyer who sues in court?

Comment: @nnnnnn, yes. It is.

Comment: @Xanne, sorry my mistake. In Italy a lawyer has various possibilities to take appropriate action to collect debts.

Comment: insoluto sounds like insolvent, thus unable to pay, which in US could lead to bankruptcy proceedings, under which all creditors get a fair percentage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Bad debt***

> Debt from a credit sale that the creditor is unable to collect. Debt becomes bad debt when the creditor has made all reasonable efforts to collect the debt but has been unable to do so. …
>   ([TFD Financial](https://financial-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/bad+debt))

"I always entrust to a lawyer the case of a bad debt."

See also *[Doubtful debt](http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/doubtful-debt.html)* (BusinessDictionary) and "[*The difference between bad debt and doubtful debt*](https://www.accountingtools.com/articles/what-is-the-difference-between-bad-debt-and-doubtful-debt.html)" (AccountingTools)

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Insolvency is the legal term used to describe a debtor who is unable to pay his debts.

"I always entrust to lawyers cases of insolvency" is a fine sentence